# Does this optimization, $\min n_1+n_2 ~\text{s.t.}~ \frac{9}{n_1}+\frac{2}{n_2} \le \epsilon$, make sense?

Tags: optimization

Suppose $n_1$ and $n_2$ are positive integer numbers. How can I approach this problem:

$$\min n_1+n_2 \\~\text{s.t.}~\frac{9}{n_1}+\frac{2}{n_2} \le \epsilon$$

Comment: get some graph paper and carefully draw, say, $$ \frac{9}{x} + \frac{2}{y} = 11  $$ for positive $x,y.$

Comment: In positive reals, you would have got the min as $\dfrac{(3+\sqrt2)^2}\epsilon$, when $(n_1, n_2) = \dfrac{3+\sqrt2}\epsilon \cdot (3, \sqrt2)$, so you might want to search for solutions nearby...